# Fire onchange for combo box programatically using javascript in IE not working

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I want to call onchange function dynamically when user change value of another combo box.
My code is as under :

**HTML**

```
<select name="vbitratecontrol0" id="combo1" onchange="set()">;
      <option value="0">None</option>
      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>
  </select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function fun(){
      document.getElementById(combo1).onChange();
}
```

when function fun is called, onchange of combo1 should be fired which is working fine in FF but not in IE6,7,8.
fun I m calling from another method.

Please help...
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select name="vbitratecontrol0" id="combo1" onchange="set()">;
      <option value="0">None</option>
      <option value="1">A</option>
      <option value="2">B</option>
  </select>

<script>

function fireEvent(element,event){
    if (document.createEventObject){
    // dispatch for IE
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
    }
    else{
    // dispatch for firefox + others
    var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
    evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
function set(){alert("asd");}

function fun(){
      fireEvent(document.getElementById("combo1"), "change");;
}

fun();
</script>
```

HTH!